# We Want YOU for Community Moderation

Tags: support, faq-proposed, moderation

> [*"[The Workplace] is built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about the workplace."*](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/about)
>
> [image: We want YOU for community moderation]

With great power comes [great responsibility](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/?tab=moderation). So as a user of this site who wants to make it even better, what the heck can I do anyway?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This site is designed for **you** the users, and we want to help make it as easy for you as possible to take ownership and shape our community. All improvement starts with a little step from you, our community, so why not start today?

1. [Vote early, vote often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)
2. Use [your superpowers for good](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/?tab=moderation)
3. Help shape our site [by posting on meta](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

#### Vote Early, Vote Often

Voting is at the core of the Stack Exchange Model. It helps identify the useful (and not so useful) information that we collect from our users. [A rising tide lifts all boats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rising_tide_lifts_all_boats) and voting adds to our [reputation economy](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) which lets our users do more and better moderate our community.

So when you're browsing around the site, and you find a question or answer to be good or bad, click those little arrows to the left of it! It will help us be a more useful resource to future visitors.

#### Use Your Privileges

As you gain reputation, you get access to [all sorts of magical powers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/?tab=moderation) that will help you moderate the site:

- 3,000 review [close votes](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/close) and [reopen votes](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/reopen)
- 2,000 review [suggested edits](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) and [low quality posts](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts)
- 500 review [late answers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers) and [first posts](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts)
- 125 vote down
- 15 [flag posts](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)
- 15 vote up

If you notice a funky orange number at the top of your screen, it means there is something productive you can do:

> [image: Top Bar Image]

What are you waiting for? That's 42* things that can be done!

<sup>* Review queue items may differ depending on reputation. Offer not valid in Hawaii or Alaska. Cannot be combined with any other coupon or offer. All sales are final.</sup>

#### Help Shape Our Site

If The Workplace is a company, then the main site is the office/shop floor where the work gets done. [The Workplace Meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/) is the board room/stockholders meeting, and you're invited to help shape our direction.

As you grow with the site, you will probably notice some things that can be improved, or things that you have questions about. That's what meta is for. Feel free to post here any time to:

1. Get support on site features with the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag
2. Help discuss and define site scope and community moderation with the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag
3. Suggest improvements to make our site even better with the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag
4. Report problems with the site not working properly with the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag